# How to create a script to restart a JAR file and get output in a terminal?

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar

I have used the following scripting for start and stop a jar file.

```
**start.sh**
#!/bin/bash
nohup nice java -jar Server.jar > ./Server.out 2>&1 &

**stop.sh**
#!/bin/bash
kill `ps -ef | grep Server.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

Now I want to merge both scripts and create a new restart script. I also want this script output in a terminal instead of a text file(Server.out).

Would appreciate any kind of input/help.

Answer (score 1):

You can either put the commands of the two sripts after each other (`kill` first, `java` second) or just call the two scipts in the appropriate order.

The idea is that restart is basically equivalent to killing the current running version and starting a new one.

To avoid the output to a file, remove the `> ./Server.out` part.

Edit: removed note about removing the redirection part as I misread the `grep` part of the `kill` script

Update: Missed the `nohup` part of the script: with `nohup` you *need* to redirect output to a file, because the process is detached from the terminal (see [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)).  If you *do* want to see the output in the terminal, remove `nohup` as well as the redirection to the file

Comment: Thanks for the reply Attila, I think you don't got my question properly, want to restart Server.jar file by running a single script and get that output in a terminal.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion was to put the contents of "stop.sh" and "start.sh" into a "restart.sh", so you have only one shell script that does a restart (kill+start).  If you remove the `>./Server.out` part, you will get the output on the terminal (instead of in Server.out file).  You can also use the `tee` command to have the output in the terminal _and_ in a file

Comment: Thanks Attila. I appreciate your reply and suggestion. Do you any idea about how to put restart.sh script in a cron job.

Comment: I have no experience with cron jobs, but [this](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) and [this](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) website explain how cron works and provide examples on the setup

Comment: Still not getting the output in a terminal after removing ">./Server.out" part from the script.

Comment: That is because you start the process with `nohup`, which means you cannot output to the terminal (the process is detached from the terminal, so it can run even when you exit the shell -- see [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)).  You either use `nohup` and redirect output to a file, or remove `nohup` and then you can see the output in the terminal.  However, if you are running the script via cron, you won't get a terminal for the process anyway, so you should redirect output to a file